# ASP.NET SQL query not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, iis

Getting issues with my following code. What I basically created below is that when a user logs in to my site they will hit this aspx page and this will check if you are part of `group_id` 1001 or not. From a database perspective I made sure that my test login username is in my DB with `group_ID` 1001 but returning as false thinking that I dont have the `group_id`. I think it maybe my SQL query tried the `@username` to `'" & username & "'` but still returning false. Not seeing any other issues but hoping to see if anyone caught where my mistake is. My money is on the SQL query somewhere but nothing I do it fixes the issue.

```
<%@ import namespace="System.Data" %> 
<%@ import namespace="MySql.data.MySqlclient" %> 
<%@ import namespace="MySql.data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection" %> 

    <Script runat="server"> 
        Sub page_load()
            Dim username As String = Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\") + 1))
            Dim dbconn As MySqlConnection
            Dim mySqlCommand As MySqlCommand
            Dim counter As Integer
            Dim isInGroup As Boolean
            Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_staff WHERE username = @username AND group_id = 1001;"

            dbconn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=imc_directory_tool;user=Directory_Admin;port=3306;password=IMCisgreat2014;")
            dbconn.Open()

            mySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, dbconn)
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
            counter = mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
            If isInGroup = counter > 0 Then
                Response.Write("You are part of group_id 1001")
            Else
                Response.Write("You are not part of group_id 1001")
            End If
            dbconn.Close()
        End Sub
    </Script>
```

Comment: take the strSQL after construction and try running it directly on the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for a Boolean is false. So after your declaration:

```
Dim isInGroup As Boolean
```

isInGroup = False

This means that your code

```
If isInGroup = counter > 0 Then
    Response.Write("You are part of group_id 1001")
Else
    Response.Write("You are not part of group_id 1001")
End If
```

Is actually:

```
If False = (counter > 0) Then
    Response.Write("You are part of group_id 1001")
Else
    Response.Write("You are not part of group_id 1001")
End If
```

And when your username and group combination is found in the database

```
(counter > 0) = True
```

I don't know why you're using the isInGroup Boolean but if you need it for other code further down then i suggest you first set the boolean value then test it where required.

```
isInGroup = counter > 0

If isInGroup = True Then
    Response.Write("You are part of group_id 1001")
Else
    Response.Write("You are not part of group_id 1001")
End If
```

Comment: you da man 5uperdan it worked, really appreciate this. im still learning alot trying to get this to work.

Comment: @DanielEllison Thanks! There's a lot of work already done for you in the .Net framework with respect to membership and groups and stuff which might be worth checking out if you haven't already. Any search for asp.net membership will pull a load of results and the official asp.net site has a section dedicated to it: http://www.asp.net/identity